# How to calculate the probability of occurrence of the dependent variable in spline logistic regression analysis?

Tags: splines

I know how the probability of the dependent variable is calculated using the regression equation:
P(1)    =   exp(Y')/(1 + exp(Y'))
But I do not know how it calculated in a spline binary logistic regression.
[image]

Comment: I assume you're using the `splines` package. As stated in the help `?bs`, the function `bs` uses B-splines. The documentation has a citation to Hastie, T. J. (1992) *Generalized additive models.* Chapter 7 of Statistical Models in S eds J. M. Chambers and T. J. Hastie, Wadsworth & Brooks/Cole. There are also a number of additional questions available via a search: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bsplines%5D+bs

Comment: Thank you so much.